# How to get and display datas after encoded Json?

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

I'm trying to pass user input form jquery/ajax but I couldn't get any datas from server while using json_encode() method PHP side. Everything was working fine before without using Json. I'm a bit confused how to get and to display the datas result. Do I have to decode it back?

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#keyword').keyup(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Get input form
        var keyword = $('#keyword').val();
        var path = "<?php echo site_url('controller/suggestion'); ?>";

            $.ajax({
                url: path,
                type: "POST",
                data: { search: keyword },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log('>> Data: ', data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

PHP Controller:

```
public function suggestion() {
    // Get the keyword from Ajax request
    $keyword = strip_tags($this->input->post('search'));

    if (isset($keyword) && !empty($keyword)) {
        echo '>> Search Keyword: '. $keyword;
        $this->tabResults = json_encode($this->model->findKeyword($keyword, 5));

        //print_r($this->tabResults);
        $data['searchResults'] = $this->tabResults;
        $this->load->view('results', $data);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">

        <div class="search">
            <form id="myform" method="post" action="film_controller/test">
                <input type="text" name="keywordsearch" id="keyword">
                <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
            </form>
            <div id="suggestionResult"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

---

I'm trying to add dataType: "json" and set data.searchResults;

I got an error in Firebug console:
"Update syntax error: 200 "JSON.parse: unexpected character data..."

```
$.ajax({
                url: path,
                type: "POST",
                data: { search: keyword },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log('>> Data: ', data.searchResults);
                },
                error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
                    console.log(">> Update Error Status: ", xhr.status, "Error Thrown: ", thrownError);
                }       
            });
```

In my controller:

```
    public static $tabResults = array();

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->tabResults = self::$tabResults;
}
public function suggestion() {
    // Get the keyword from Ajax request
    $keyword = strip_tags($this->input->post('search'));

    if (isset($keyword) && !empty($keyword)) {
        echo '>> Search Keyword: '. $keyword;
        $this->tabResults = json_encode($this->film_model->findKeyword($keyword, 5));

        print_r($this->tabResults);
        $data['searchResults'] = $this->tabResults;
        $this->load->view('results', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: JSON's just a method for encapsulating a native data structure into a plain string, using (J)ava(S)cript (O)bject (N)otation. Your PHP data structure gets converted to a JSON string, which jquery will convert into a native Javascript equivalent structure for you.

Comment: How I can call my PHP data structure ($this->tabResults) once it has been converted to Json string in HTML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want return json data you don't need load a view. Just return the json encoded data.

```
if (isset($keyword) && ! empty($keyword))
{
    $this->tabResults = json_encode($this->model->findKeyword($keyword, 5));

    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request())
    {
        return print $this->tabResults;
    }

    $data['searchResults'] = $this->tabResults;
    $this->load->view('results', $data);
}
```

Comment: Then How can I call $this->tabResults in Jquery? success:function(data) { console.log('>> Data', data.tabResults); } doesn't work Firebug show Data: undefined

Comment: Your AJAX call looks good. But you are returning a string, not an object. So just check with console.log('>> Data', data);

Comment: Actually I'm returning an array ($this->tabResults). I DON'T GET anything back when calling console.log("Data: ", data); Kinda weird! What did I do wrong?

Comment: Yes, But when you apply json_encode to your array it is converted to a string. As Sakthi said set dataType=json and the server response should be something like `return print(json_encode((object) array('tabResults' => $this->model->findKeyword($keyword, 5))));` In that case you will obtain `data.tabResults`. In general all your steps looks good.

Answer (score 1):

There is the `dataType` attribute in the jquery `$_ajax()` function. You have to set it as json.

If you set like that, the result will be in the form of object. So, You have to access like object.(ie., data.[the text you sent from the server side]).

The below url may help U.

```
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
```

If You have still problem with this, plz let me know..

Comment: Agree, good point. Moreover the server response should be something like `return print(json_encode((object) array('tabResults' => $this->model->findKeyword($keyword, 5))));` In that case qpixo could get `data.tabResults`.

Comment: Hey, I found a way to display using $this->output->set_output(json_encode(...)); but when there's no data, I want to add a custom error message. In Jquery where should I add it? I had a hard time to figure this out.

Comment: they is the way, U can set like this json_encode(array('status'=>0)) for one status and another json_encode(array('status'=>1)) and you can check it in js and add your custom message in js..!